# How to return a Google Image Search based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, google-custom-search

I want to make a web app that generates an outfit based on the weather of the location they choose.

Here is what I have so far: https://codepen.io/anchpags/pen/bMpjxX

```
 <html>
  <head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://toolness.github.io/weather-outfit-fun/weather-outfit.css">
<script src="http://toolness.github.io/weather-outfit-fun/weather-outfit.js"></script>

    <script>
function getForecastOutfit(forecast) {
  if (forecast.temp.f > 0) {
    return "http://some/picture";
  }
  return "http://toolness.github.io/weather-outfit-fun/img/eskimo-lomen-1915.jpg";
}

    </script>

    <title>What Should I Wear Today?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>What Should I Wear Today?</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me understand how to use Custom Search API to return images based on the weather?

I.e. if it is < 40 degrees website then the images result page of "warm outfits" search will display.

I'm very new at coding so a good explanation will be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of query parameters. You can filter it with those parameters.
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick exemple on how to use the google search API here
https://github.com/MomoPlay/Google-Custom-Search-exemple
It search for images and display them.